# Bootstrap Carousel using loop and pug

Tags: bootstrap-4, pug, carousel

I'm trying to create a carousel using bootstrap and Pug. I want the carousel to take images and data from my mongoDB and display it slide by slide. I can get the data no problem but I cant present it the right way. The images just list or stack on one slide. I can get it to work correctly if i hard code it slide by slide but i want it to be dynamic so if something is added to the DB it automatically creates a new slide. Any suggestion would be a big help. Thanks in advance.

```
#carouselExampleControls.carousel.slide(data-ride='carousel' style ='width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto')
    .carousel-inner
      .carousel-item.active
              - let values = listedGames.content
                  each val in values ? values : ['There are no values']
                    .carousel-item
                    li= JSON.stringify(val.title) + ' created by ' + JSON.stringify(val.creator) + '('+ JSON.stringify(val.year) +')'
                    img.d-block.w-100(src=val.url, alt="Image Title")

    a.carousel-control-prev(href='#carouselExampleControls' role='button' data-slide='prev')
        span.carousel-control-prev-icon(aria-hidden='true')
        span.sr-only Previous
    a.carousel-control-next(href='#carouselExampleControls' role='button' data-slide='next')
        span.carousel-control-next-icon(aria-hidden='true')
        span.sr-only Next
```

Comment: Does the indentation in the code in the question match the indentation in your code locally?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing this, removed the .carousel-item.active from the top then added an if statement to set the first item as an active slide

```html
#carouselExampleControls.carousel.slide(data-ride='carousel' style ='width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto')
    .carousel-inner
      - let values = listedGames.content
          each val, index in values ? values : ['There are no values']
            if(index === 0)
              .carousel-item.active
                p= JSON.stringify(val.title) + ' created by ' + JSON.stringify(val.creator) + '('+ JSON.stringify(val.year) +')'
                img.d-block.w-100(src=val.url, alt="Image Title")
            else     
              .carousel-item
                p= JSON.stringify(val.title) + ' created by ' + JSON.stringify(val.creator) + '('+ JSON.stringify(val.year) +')'
                img.d-block.w-100(src=val.url, alt="Image Title")

    a.carousel-control-prev(href='#carouselExampleControls' role='button' data-slide='prev')
        span.carousel-control-prev-icon(aria-hidden='true')
        span.sr-only Previous
    a.carousel-control-next(href='#carouselExampleControls' role='button' data-slide='next')
        span.carousel-control-next-icon(aria-hidden='true')
        span.sr-only Next
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that img is not placed under carousel-item class.Just intent the li and img to a tab so that it comes under carousel-item.

Comment: Thanks for the help, managed to get it working another way though, i posted it above.